# Connecting the MenuItem click signal. found solution

Tags: menu, gtkmm

I am using gtkmm 2.4 and C++ on Red Hat RHEL 8. I am using a `Gtk::Fixed` layout. I want to be able to place my widgets where I want them.

I am trying to implement a File Menu. I am trying to build the File Menu manually. I have everything working except connecting to the signal when I click the "OPEN" menu item. How do I connect to the "OPEN" click signal to the `OpenStub` method?

Here is some code snippets:

```
TestWindow.h
Class TestWindow   :  public Gtk::window
{
    TestWindow();

    void OpenStub();

   // menu
   Gtk::MenuItem File;
   Gtk::Menu* FileMenu;
   Gtk::MenuItem* Open;

   // layout widgets
   Gtk::Fixed fixed;
   Gtk::ScrolledWindow scrolledWindow;
};

TestWindow.cc
TestWindow::TestWindow()
{

   // add scrolled window
   add(scrolledWindow);

   // add fixed layout
   add(fixed);

    // File Menu
   File = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem(“_File”));
   FileMenu = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Menu);
   Open = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem(“_Open”));
   FileMenu->append(*Open);
   File->set_submenu(*FileMenu);

   Gtk::MenuBar* menubar = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuBar);
   Menubar->append(*File);

  //add menu
  fixed.put(menubar, 0, 0);

}

void TestWindow::OpenStub()
{
    std::cout << “Open Stub “ << std::endl;
}
```

I have found the solution.

Solution:

```
       Open = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem(“_Open”));
       Open->signal_activate().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&OpenStub));
       FileMenu->append(*Open);
```

Comment: Good! I wouls suggest posting it as a self answer!